# How to set an arbitrary seed to the --random-sort option of Linux SORT?

Tags: linux, sorting, pipe

In man page of SORT, it says you can set a random source like:

```
$ sort some.txt --random-sort --random-source=/dev/urandom
```

I want to an standard output text to the source like:

```
$ sort some.txt --random-sort --random-source=`date +"%m%d%H%M"`
```

But this only says:

> open failed: 11021103: No such file or directory

How can I do this?

Comment: `--random-source` requires a **FILE** (so a device/regular file/fifo etc). I think you may have assumed that `--random-source` sets a seed for a Pseudo RNG. It needs a file with entropy already inside it or some some type of device that can generate it (like `/dev/urandom`, `/dev/random` etc). Is there a reason you can't use `/dev/urandom`?

Answer (score -1):

Here's a simple python script that takes a seed and outputs random bytes:

```
> cat rand_bits.py
import random
import sys

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    rng = random.Random(int(sys.argv[-1]))
else:
    rng = random.Random(0xBA5EBA11)

try:
    while True:
        sys.stdout.write(chr(rng.getrandbits(8)))
except (IOError, KeyboardInterrupt):
    pass
sys.stdout.close()
```

You can just feed those bytes straight into sort:

```
> sort <(seq 25) -R --random-source=<(python rand_bits.py 5) 
8
2
4
7
10
19
17
11
3
20
14
18
1
16
25
12
5
21
24
23
22
9
15
13
6
```

By the way, the input can be *any* file, but the file better be long enough!

```
> sort <(seq 25) -R --random-source=<(date +"%m%d%H%M")   
sort: /dev/fd/12: end of file
> sort <(seq 25) -R --random-source=/dev/sda1
3
13
24
5
10
16
4
17
12
18
14
2
6
15
23
21
19
11
9
1
20
25
22
8
7
```

Comment: Since the OP was trying to set a seed from the date/time I wondering if this would be closer to what they are looking for: `sort <(seq 25) -R --random-source=<(python rand_bits.py $(date +'%N'))`

Comment: That would replicate the intent of his example yes, but if he's not picking the seed he may as well just use `/dev/urandom` as others have said.